# Oldest and Newest Timestamp for separate WHERE clauses - Conditional Aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with account id's, event types and event timestamps.

I need to get the **oldest** event of one type and the **newest** event of another type for each account.

I have managed to make queries that pull each of those pieces of information individually, but I can't get it into one query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id, MIN(event_timestamp) 
    FROM table
    WHERE event_type = 'x'
    GROUP BY event_type, account_id

    SELECT DISTINCT account_id, MAX(event_timestamp) 
    FROM table
    WHERE event_type = 'y'
    GROUP BY event_type, account_id
```

Does anyone have tips about how this could be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not put "SOLVED" into the title - just accept the answer that solved your problem. Only then will your question be marked as "solved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT account_id,
       MIN(event_timestamp) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'x'),
       MAX(event_timestamp) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'Y')
FROM table
WHERE event_type IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY account_id;
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never used (correctly) in a query with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for you help (and the tip).

I'll be sure to accept this answer as soon as I can